# How do I set the selected-value of a drop down box in Blazor?

Tags: c#, combobox, blazor

I've created a Blazor server app targeting .NET 6.0.

I then add a combo-box to the default Counter.razor page like this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<p>
    <label>
        Select a car:
        <select @onchange="SelectedCarsChanged" >
            <option value="">Select a car</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            <option value="jeep">Jeep</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</p>
```

Here's the @code section after the combo-box addition.

```
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
    string SelectedCar = "";
    void SelectedCarsChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value is not null)
        {
            SelectedCar = (string)e.Value;
        }
    }
```

The user selects a car and then presses the "Click me" button.

How do I reset the combo-box to "Select a car" in the IncrementCount() routine when that happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor select dropdown set active value by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599131/blazor-select-dropdown-set-active-value-by-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, bind SelectedCar to select like this

```
 <select @bind=@SelectedCar>
            <option value="">Select a car</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            <option value="jeep">Jeep</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        </select>
```

And select SelectedCar like this

```
 private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        SelectedCar = "";
    }
```

Comment: No, because the combo-box continues to show the previously selected value.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what you mean by previously selected value

Comment: I tested code,   initially it shows "select a car" and if I select any car from select it shows selected car and if I click on click me button   select shows "select a car". Is not it what you expect

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Thank you! I will mark this as the correct answer, and upvote it as soon as I'm permitted.